# Format datetime in XSLT

Tags: datetime, xslt, transformation

I have a timestamp field (MSG_TIMESTAMP) that retrieved from DB would need to transform the format from 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF3' to 'yyyyMMddHHmm'. Can I format using format-datetime fuction in XSLT file as per following?

From

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(//results/result/function[@name='ADD-TO-RESPONSE']/resultItem/property[key='MSG_TIMESTAMP']/value, '[]', '')"/>
```

To

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(//results/result/function[@name='ADD-TO-RESPONSE']/resultItem/property[key=format-date('MSG_TIMESTAMP']/value, '[Y0001]/[M01]/[D01]/[H01]/[m01]', '')"/>
```

Comment: What's the difference between `YYYY` and `yyyy` or `DD` and `dd`? What is `24MISS`?

Comment: No difference between YYYY and yyyy or DD and dd. 24MISS is simply return time format in 24- hours format. The expected format is just to get rid of the seconds part.

Comment: I've no idea why you think translate() would help with this, but before you use it again, I would recommend checking the spec. Your particular invocation will remove open- and close square brackets from the input string, which seems completely unrelated to your stated requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the first 12 characters of a value (which it seems you do), you can do that with `substring()`. No date-formatting functions required:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(
   translate(//results/result/function[@name='ADD-TO-RESPONSE']/resultItem/property[key='MSG_TIMESTAMP']/value, '[]', ''),
   1, 12)"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, current value is like 20171120125125442, expected to see 201711201251